# OS X Server 3.0 (Mavericks) Wiki / WebSites / Xcode

Tags: macos, xcode, websites, server.app

I have a domain name registered called mydomain.com. I have a static IP address from my ISP. I set the dns information on GoDaddy for my domain as follows to point to my ISP:

- mydomain.com A record 65.0.0.1
- vpn.mydomain.com A record 65.0.0.1
- www.mydomain.com CNAME mydomain.com (Not sure if this is needed)

At home, I have an AirPort Extreme with VPN and Mail opened up to pass through (port forwarding) to my Mac Mini running Server 3. My Mac Mini host name is server.mydomain.com.

I have DNS, File Sharing, Open Directory, Profile Manager, VPN, Wiki, Websites, Mail, and Xcode services running on the server.

On my Mac Mini Server I enabled Xcode and Wiki and disabled Websites, I open Safari, and if I go to mydomain.com I can see the Xcode page and if I click the Wiki link, it takes me to mydomain.com/wiki. However, if I enable Websites, neither the Xcode or wiki pages work anymore.

How can I set it up so that going to mydomain.com points to Websites folder. Going to mydomain.com/wiki OR if I can't have that, I wouldn't mind wiki.mydomain.com instead to display the wiki page. Same with Xcode (i.e. Xcode.mydomain.com)?

Note: I didn't port forward Xcode, wiki, or websites in the Airport Extreme because I want it only accessible when connected over VPN.

Edit: I can get Websites and Wiki to work together, but turning on Xcode changes the way mydomain.com is accessed. Xcode should be accessed by going to domain.com/xcode however domain.com still shows the same output as /xcode. If I turn Xcode off domain.com/ takes me to my html page and domain.com/wiki shows me the wiki page.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Resolution:

Remove /xcode and /wiki from Websites -> Server Website -> Index Files